# Seeking expertise on Power BI dynamic counting and grouping measures

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a power BI challenge.  I have a category that has say 5 values, all text values.  I have something like 3 of those values make up 90% of the total count.  I want a way to dynamically say count the total (based on count of text string values) for each category and add up all category values.  If the total of any category is <1000 then create an 'other' group that adds all categories where counts are <1000

for example:

Hot Dog - 5000
Hamburger - 3500
Sausage -50
Coleslaw - 400
Mac n Cheese 800

On my chart there would be 3 series.  One for Hot Dog, one for Hamburger, and an 'Other' series where the count would be 1250.  The count is aggregated to 1250 bc the logic sees that sausage, coleslaw, and mac all have values less than 1000 and sums them.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can use the pattern that Alberto Ferrari used in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVvlEHKr_0o